# How would you write a test for the `Iconv.new("UTF8//IGNORE", ...)` idiom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This Iconv idiom transcodes a string to UTF-8 and drops characters that can't be transliterated:

```
require "iconv"

def normalize(text)
  Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8').iconv(text.dup)
end
```

How would you actually write a test for this?

Edit: I ended up simplifying the question since I realized the context of trying to test this in a Rails `# encoding: utf-8` spec file was complicating the issue. So now the bounty is kind of silly but I'll reward it anyways if someone can show a test I can work off of.

Comment: Maybe, look at this: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/42664369166/fight-back-utf-8-invalid-byte-sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct Strings from a byte array using the [#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) method. This way, you can easily generate an invalid/bad string and use it in a test.

Example:

```
describe "#normalize" do
  it "should remove/ignore invalid characters" do
    # this "string" equals "Mandados de busca do caso Megaupload considerados inv\xE1lidos - Tecnologia - Sol"
    bad_string = [77, 97, 110, 100, 97, 100, 111, 115, 32, 100, 101, 32, 98, 117, 115, 99, 97, 32, 100, 111, 32, 99, 97, 115, 111, 32, 77, 101, 103, 97, 117, 112, 108, 111, 97, 100, 32, 99, 111, 110, 115, 105, 100, 101, 114, 97, 100, 111, 115, 32, 105, 110, 118, 225, 108, 105, 100, 111, 115, 32, 45, 32, 84, 101, 99, 110, 111, 108, 111, 103, 105, 97, 32, 45, 32, 83, 111, 108].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')

    normalize(bad_string).should == 'Mandados de busca do caso Megaupload considerados invlidos - Tecnologia - Sol'
  end
end
```

(I'm sorry for the rather long test string, I just couldn't find a shorter example in my code)

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `force_encoding` in your test? Would it emulate the process of passing a string through a `accept-charset=utf8` form or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The thing you want to achieve with your `normalize` method is to convert invalid utf8 strings into valid ones. So to test your method, you first have to create an invalid utf8 string. And the method above is the easiest way I found to achieve that: use `pack` to create a string from a collection of bytes and then `force_encoding` to mark this string as utf8...

Answer (score 1):

testing this in rails, even with an `#encoding` set is possible.

just use an encoding-step like URL-escapes:

```
require "iconv"
require "cgi"

def normalize(text)
  Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8').iconv(text)
end

puts normalize(CGI.unescape("m%FCstring")) # => mstring
```

so with that you could write an assertion.

when you are using ruby 1.9 Iconv is deprecated and you should use the `encode` methods of string!

Comment: Yeah, this question came about because I'm trying to replace Iconv with `String#encode` for Ruby 2.0.0 compatibility and I'm trying to defend against regressions.

Comment: so the answer does not fit your question? or why dont you except it?